# Failed to establish a new connection using python winrm

Tags: python, windows, winrm

When trying to connect multiple instances in a given CIDR range using python winrm. We are getting the following exception.

```
import wimrm

url = "http://10.24.x.x:5985/wsman"
username = admin@domain.com
password = xxxx

session = winrm.Session(url, auth=(username, password), transport='ntlm', server_cert_validation = 'ignore')
```

EXCEPTION HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.24.x.x', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10055] An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full'))

When tried connecting to a single server we were able to connect it. Would appreciate if provided with a solution.

Python 3.6
pywinrm 0.3.0

Comment: What happened with this error?